In "Big Sky" by Kate Atkinson, who was following Crystal?
I just finished reading Big Sky by Kate Atkinson. I really like her work in general but I feel some of the plotlines' endings were a bit of a mess in this one. Some very poorly explained and a lot of the ending seems hurried.
In particular:

 Who was following Crystal and why did they kidnap Harry and Candace to keep her quiet?
 I assume they were either Tommy's henchman Vassily and Jason, who were never accounted for, and / or working for another party. But then who rescued them?

Trying to rationalise this:



 The silver BMW belongs to MI5? they don't get involved except to rescue Harry (and Felicity whom I thought was being murdered in an alley)




 The kidnappers work for Nicholas and want to keep Crystal quiet.




 They may or may not be Vassily and Jason.



Perhaps I overlooked some subtle clues?
or perhaps the author was being forced / rushing to meet a deadline?

How is any of that a spoiler?

Please consider removing the spoiler markup. It is inaccessible to keyboard users.

How do you do an accessible spoiler without spoiling things?
